# A project with an Output type of class library cannot be started directly asp.net mvc

Tags: visual-studio

I just inherited a .Net application and now having trouble starting it up.  When I try to run it I get the error:

> A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly.  In order to debug this project , add an executable project to this solution which references the library project.  Set executable project as the start up project.

To try and resole this issue I went the solutions explorer, right click on the solution and click on properties then this wind[image]ow below popped up.

I changed the single startup project to all my existing options and still no luck.

Please assist

Comment: which is suppose to be the start up project? all the projects in the posted image look like class libraries. And as you have already seen class libraries can be started.

Comment: you have to create new project which is executable, currently no any projects in your solution which is executable so this error throw

Comment: @HiteshKansagara That solution doesn't make sense for an mvc web app. Something in the scaffolding has been disconnected.